# i want to implement a gui for a facial recognition program that uses CLIs

Tags: python, tkinter, command-line-interface, opencv

i am not too good at writing full fledged GUIs.
so basically what i am trying to do is create a GUI for my facial recognition program using tkinter, instead of users manually entering command line arguments in the command prompt, and i want the output to be like this(original image in the left panel, and the recognized image on the right.
the code here is a working code that allows user to input arguments in the command prompt.

thanks in advance.

```
import face_recognition
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-e", "--encodings", required=True,
    help="path to serialized db of facial encodings")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--detection-method", type=str, default="cnn",
    help="face detection model to use: either `hog` or `cnn`")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the known faces and embeddings
print("[INFO] loading encodings...")
data = pickle.loads(open(args["encodings"], "rb").read())

# load the input image and convert it from BGR to RGB
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# detect the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding boxes corresponding
# to each face in the input image, then compute the facial embeddings
# for each face
print("[INFO] recognizing faces...")
boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,
    model=args["detection_method"])
encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)

# initialize the list of names for each face detected
names = []

# loop over the facial embeddings
for encoding in encodings:
    # attempt to match each face in the input image to our known
    # encodings
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
        encoding)
    name = "Unknown"

    # check to see if we have found a match
    if True in matches:
        # find the indexes of all matched faces then initialize a
        # dictionary to count the total number of times each face
        # was matched
        matchedIdxs = [i for (i, b) in enumerate(matches) if b]
        counts = {}

        # loop over the matched indexes and maintain a count for
        # each recognized face face
        for i in matchedIdxs:
            name = data["names"][i]
            counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1

        # determine the recognized face with the largest number of
        # votes (note: in the event of an unlikely tie Python will
        # select first entry in the dictionary)
        name = max(counts, key=counts.get)
    
    # update the list of names
    names.append(name)

# loop over the recognized faces
for ((top, right, bottom, left), name) in zip(boxes, names):
    # draw the predicted face name on the image
    cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    y = top - 15 if top - 15 > 15 else top + 15
    cv2.putText(image, name, (left, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.75, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and this is what i have tried

```
import face_recognition
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
def select_image():
    
    # grab a reference to the image panels
    global panelA, panelB

    # open a file chooser dialog and allow the user to select an input
    # image
    imagepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    encodingspath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    # ensuring a file path is selected
    # construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-d", "--detection-method", type=str, default="cnn",
    help="face detection model to use: either `hog` or `cnn`")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    if len(imagepath and encodingspath) > 0:
        data = pickle.loads(open(encodingspath, "rb").read())
        # load the input image and convert it from BGR to RGB
        initial_image = cv2.imread(imagepath)
        image = cv2.imread(imagepath)
        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # detect the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding boxes corresponding
        # to each face in the input image, then compute the facial embeddings
        # for each face
        print("[INFO] recognizing faces...")
        boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb, model=args["detection_method"])
        encodingspath = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)

        # initialize the list of names for each face detected
        names = []

        # loop over the facial embeddings
        for encoding in encodingspath:
            # attempt to match each face in the input image to our known
            # encodings
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(data(encodingspath), encoding)
            name = "Unknown"

            # check to see if we have found a match
            if True in matches:
                # find the indexes of all matched faces then initialize a
                # dictionary to count the total number of times each face
                # was matched
                matchedIdxs = [i for (i, b) in enumerate(matches) if b]
                counts = {}

                # loop over the matched indexes and maintain a count for
                # each recognized face face
                for i in matchedIdxs:
                    name = data["names"][i]
                    counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1

                    # determine the recognized face with the largest number of
                    # votes (note: in the event of an unlikely tie Python will
                    # select first entry in the dictionary)
                    name = max(counts, key=counts.get)
    
                    # update the list of names
                    names.append(name)

                    # loop over the recognized faces
                    for ((top, right, bottom, left), name) in zip(boxes, names):
                        # draw the predicted face name on the image
                        cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                        y = top - 15 if top - 15 > 15 else top + 15
                        cv2.putText(image, name, (left, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0, 255, 0), 2)

                        # show the output image
                        #cv2.imshow("Image", image)
                        #cv2.waitKey(0)

                        # if the panels are None, initialize them
                        if panelA is None or panelB is None:
                            # the first panel will store our original image
                            panelA = Label(image=initial_image)
                            panelA.image = initial_image
                            panelA.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

                            # while the second panel will store the recognized image
                            panelB = Label(image=image)
                            panelB.image = image
                            panelB.pack(side="right", padx=10, pady=10)
                            # otherwise, update the image panels
                        else:
                            # update the pannels
                            panelA.configure(image=initial_image)
                            panelB.configure(image=image)
                            panelA.image = initial_image
                            panelB.image = image
                            # initialize the window toolkit along with the two image panels
                            root = Tk()
                            panelA = None
                            panelB = None

                            # create a button, then when pressed, will trigger a file chooser
                            # dialog and allow the user to select an input image; then add the
                            # button the GUI
                            btn = Button(root, text="Select an image", command=select_image)
                            btn.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", padx="10", pady="10")

                            # kick off the GUI
                            root.mainloop()
```

when i run my attempt it doesnt display anything

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks, *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Comment: i have already added them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep your command-line tool as it is and let the GUI invoke it after the arguments are selected. Therefore, it can be still used from command-line if you wish.

To get you started consider something like this (assuming your cli tools is named `face_recognition`)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.image = ""

    def create_widgets(self):
        tk.Button(self, text="Choose image...", command=self.get_image_filename).pack(fill=tk.X)
        # TODO: add a way to enter all the desired arguments... 
        tk.Button(self, text="Run", command=self.run_face_recognition).pack(fill=tk.X)
        tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.master.destroy).pack(fill=tk.X)

    def get_image_filename(self):
        self.image = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()

    def run_face_recognition(self):
        subprocess.run([sys.executable, "/path/to/face_recognition.py", "--image", self.image, "args..."])

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: As the command line tool does not have the `shebang` line, `bash` or `sh` will be used as the interpreter if it is executed directly (assume it has the `x` attribute enabled).  So better explicitly use Python to execute the command line tool.

Comment: i tried, but i think i'm going about it  the wrong way.

Comment: @acw1668 can you please shed more lights, its confusing

Comment: edited to show how to invoke `python` in case you don't have shebang and executable permission.

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt seem to work. the command prompt window opens then closes almost immediately.

Comment: @AyomideOmotayo Show the arguments you pass to `subprocess.run()`.  Also better use `sys.executable` instead of `"python"`.

Comment: Perhaps you need https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano thanks a lot and i followed you on twitter.